# Undo last commit, but leave repository unchanged

Tags: git

I just did add and commit on my repository, did not push it yet. Now there are files in the commit that actually needed to be ignored. So I need to undo that add and commit, but all files need to stay the same. What to do?

Comment: I have searched, but most questions and also the link just mentioned don't explicitly ask for the repository to stay the way it is. So I was unsure. But now I see the `reset --soft` option is what I need. Too bad it is downvoted this quicly..

Comment: the `git reset --soft HEAD^` does not touch the state of the repository, it just removes last commit and put back all committed files in the index like it was just before you've done the `git commit`. Then you just need to remove the file you want to put out of the commit from the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just for that kind of problems, I have added in my `~/.gitconfig` file the following alias:

```
[alias]
undo = reset --soft HEAD^
```

Comment: So, does that make the following command available: `git undo` ?

Comment: Nice! Now I only need to set it as a default for git, I will probably use that more often.. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use git-extras (cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/8487487/1290438) that provides a nice `git undo` alias.

Comment: The things you can learn in a day! Thanks!